# HTML File Upload - why use IFrame

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have been trying to get file uploads working in IE8.  To only solution I have seen is posting to an IFrame.  Why is this done?  Is it not possible to have a simple form e.g.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Which submits directly to PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

Why would an IFrame be needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iframe method is really very easy.
Basically you use a iframe to upload the file instead of the main window to upload it, but you do not need to use iframes.

**Method 1**

This is a good tutorial on the subject: http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-easiest-asynchronous-upload-file-ajax-upload/

HTML:

```
<form id="my_form" name="form" action="upload.php" method="POST" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<div id="main">
<input name="my_files" id="my_file" size="27" type="file" />
<input type="button" name="action" value="Upload" onclick="redirect()"/>
<iframe id='my_iframe' name='my_iframe' src="">
</iframe>
</div>    
</form>
```

JS:

```
function redirect()
{
//'my_iframe' is the name of the iframe
document.getElementById('my_form').target = 'my_iframe';
document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
}
```

PHP:

```
$uploaddir = '/images/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['my_files']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_files']['my_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "success";
} else {
echo "error";
}
```

**2. AJAX METHOD**

JS:

```
function submitForm() {
        var formData = new FormData($('#imageForum')[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/FileUpload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('posted')
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            return false;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="imageForum" action="javascript:submitForm();" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="fileUpload">File upload</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need an iframe to upload a file.

You need an iframe to upload a file **without leaving the current page** (i.e. for Ajax). Modern browsers support `FormData` which allows you to upload files with `XMLHttpRequest`.